# Regular expression for HH:MM:SS

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a reqular expression that matches HH:MM e.g. 12:23 and it is:

```
function IsValidTime(timeString)
{
    var pattern = /^\d?\d:\d{2}$/;
    if (!timeString.match(pattern))
        return false;
}
```

How do I change this line:

**var pattern = /^\d?\d:\d{2}$/;**

to check for a string that is formatted with seconds like so: **HH:MM:SS** e.g. 12:23:05

Comment: 12 or 24 hour time? Leading zeroes optional/mandatory/forbidden?

Comment: This seems pretty straight forward if you're only looking for casual validation...how do you come up with the `HH:MM` regex in the first place?

Comment: I didn't come up with it, I'm just changing an existing function to detect the extra e.g. ':12' that the seconds introduces. I don't need and range checking etc.

Comment: Your regex doesn't even match time correctly, e.g. `99:99` would be correct in your case.

Comment: I know but there is other code that does range checking after the pattern e.g. 99:99:99 is detected.

Comment: seriously? you've got a pattern that can match `hh:mm`, and you can't see from that pattern how to extend it to work with `:ss` as well? Have you actually tried to solve this before asking SO? Even with zero knowledge of regex, there ought to be enough clues in the expression you already have to get you started.

Comment: Functions not matching their expectations derived from the function name is their programmers ticket straight to hell.

Answer (score 32):

```
/^(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/
```

for 24-hour time, leading zeroes mandatory.

```
/^(?:2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/
```

for 24-hour time, leading zeroes optional.

```
/^(?:1[0-2]|0[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/
```

for 12-hour time, leading zeroes mandatory.

```
/^(?:1[0-2]|0?[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/
```

for 12-hour time, leading zeroes optional.

Answer (score 11):

Something as simple as the following should work:

```
/([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/g
```

#### Regex Explanation:

- `([01][0-9]|2[0-3])`

  - A collection of the following:
  - `[01][0-9]` the characters "0" or "1" followed by any digit between 0 and 9
  - `|` - *or*
  - `2[0-3]` the character "2" followed by a digit between 0 and 3
- `:` a literal colon
- `[0-5][0-9]` - any digit between 0 to 5 followed by any digit between 0 and 9
- `:` a literal colon
- `[0-5][0-9]` - any digit between 0 to 5 followed by any digit between 0 and 9

#### Demo:

[**Regex101**](http://regex101.com/r/uJ7fK4)

Comment: to tally with the expression from the question, you should make the leading zero optional. `[01]?`

Comment: also end of string should be added /([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$ otherwise even 12:15:16asdfad is valid using above regEx

Answer (score 0):

Basing on your regex for detecting `99:99:99`, the following regex would suffice:

```
/^\d?\d:\d{2}:\d{2}$/
```

or a bit more sophisticated

```
/^\d?\d(?::\d{2}){2}$/
```

but much better would be (because it correctly matches the ranges):

```
/^(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d$/
```

which would conform the function name `IsValidTime`...

Answer (score 0):

**Validate time in format as“ hh:mm am/pm ” in javascript**

```
function timeValidation(strTime) {
           var timeFormat = /^(?:1[0-2]|0?[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]\s?(?:am|pm)?/;
           return timeFormat.test(strTime);
       }
```

timeValidation("12:30 PM") // return true

timeValidation("12:30 ") // return false

timeValidation("27:30 AM") // return false

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

```js
            function fromTimeFunction(){
                var from_time = document.getElementById("form_time").value;
                let regex = new RegExp(/^(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/);
                if (from_time == "") {
                    document.getElementById("form_time_text").innerHTML = "Please Fill from minutes field for selected user.";
                    return "false";
                }
                if (regex.test(from_time) != false) {
                    document.getElementById("form_time_text").innerHTML = "";
                    return "true";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("form_time_text").innerHTML = "Please select from minutes field for selected user.";
                    return "false";
                }
            }
            function toTimeFunction(){
                var to_time = document.getElementById("to_time").value;
                let regex = new RegExp(/^(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/);
                if (to_time == "") {
                    document.getElementById("to_time_text").innerHTML = "Please Fill to minutes field for selected user.";
                    return "false";
                }
                if (regex.test(to_time) != false) {
                    document.getElementById("to_time_text").innerHTML = "";
                    return "true";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("to_time_text").innerHTML = "Please select to minutes field for selected user.";
                    return "false";
                }
            }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Project Details</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <div class="container" align="center">
                <div class="row mt-5">
                    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h3>Time Validation in HH:MM:SS format</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <form action="" method="POST" class="mt-5">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-5">
                                                        <label for="form_time">From Time</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form_time" onblur="fromTimeFunction()">
                                                        <p id="form_time_text" style="color:red; font-size: 11px;"></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                                        <label for="to_time">To Time</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="to_time"  onblur="toTimeFunction()">
                                                        <p id="to_time_text" style="color:red; font-size: 11px;"></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Bootstrap Link -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Delete the `enter code here` and fix the indentation of the script

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Do not post an answer with merely codes. While your solution can be useful, you should also explain why the code will fix the problem that was described in the question